# Tipping ladder equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

I try to solve a variant of the falling ladder problem, this time without a wall and the bottom of the ladder does not slide. There is a mass $m$ and the angle of the ladder with the vertical is $\phi$.

[image]

The rotating moment is caused by the gravitational force:

$$M_r = F_z l \sin \phi = m g l \sin \phi $$

Which equals the rotational inertial moment:

$$M_\phi = ml^2 \frac{d^2 \phi}{dt^2}$$

This results in the following differential equation:

$$\frac{d^2 \phi}{dt^2} = \frac{g}{l} \sin \phi$$

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Solving this differential equation as it's written requires some special functions. Typically you'd want to linearize it for small displacement by $\sin \phi \sim \phi$ and solve that.

Answer (score 1):

This is the [simple pendulum equation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum_(mathematics)). Unfortunately, there is no closed form solution (except for the trivial $\varphi=0$ unstable ladder that never slides).